# Do I need MySQL even though there is no user registration on my website?

Tags: mysql

I have made a website which does some calculations, so there is no user registration. Just a website where people can do their calculations and leave. However, do I need MySQL as part of the server? I am a bit confused on this.

Comment: To put it in short, no.

Comment: Depends if you plan on saving data.

Comment: I believe this was closed erroneously.  The answer seems obvious to me, not primarily a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (and other database engines like PostgresQL, MongoDB, and even Google's BigTable) are used for storing data outside of user sessions. If you have no need to persist data, then you have no need for a database.

Comment: So there is no need to for a database then. Thanks.